# partial distance correlation test fatal error

Tags: r, correlation

I am using pdcor.test function from energy package.

I am using it to find partial distance correlation between two variables given another data.

The problem is that there is no problem of running the pdcor.test one by one, but when I made a nested loop and run the even twice using for(i in 1:2), I get a fatal error and the R session aborts.

For your information, I used many if-else statements, but I do not think they will affect the fatal error, and the replication I used for pdcor.test is 100, which is not that big for a permutation based test.

```
test <- pdcor.test(A[,i], A[,j], A[-c(i, j)], 100)
    if(test$p.value < 0.05 & !is.na(test$p.value)){
      adj.mat[i, j] <- adj.mat[j, i] <- 1
    }
    else{
      adj.mat[i, j] <- adj.mat[j, i] <- 0
    }
```

I made a nested for loops with many pdcor.test code very similar to one above with many conditional statements.

I assume the error comes up when 100 replications made for permutation test is repeated many times.

What would be the problem, and how should I fix it?

My goal is to successfully run codes like

```
for(i in 1:25){
    for(j in 1:25){
        test <- pdcor.test(A[,i], A[,j], A[-c(i, j)], 100)
        if(test$p.value < 0.05){
            mat[i,j] <- 1
        }
        else{
            mat[i,j] <- 0
        }
    }
}
```

with many conditional statements inside j loop.

Comment: Use `pdcor.test()` in the loop not `pdcor()`. `pdcor()` only takes 3 arguments.

Comment: sorry, I edited the question, but the problem is still there

Comment: I cannot reproduce an error, the code runs fine. Can you edit the question with the error message you are getting?